# SQL left join multiple product id's

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table and need to join some data.  In table 2 there a multiple product ID's some with the but with differnt dates.

eg

```
Table 1 (Master)
Product
```

left join

Table 2

```
Product | Date 1
AA      | 01/01/2018
AA      | 01/02/2018
AB      | 01/01/2018
AC      | 01/01/2018
AC      | 01/02/2018
```

What im looking for is to have the data looking like:

```
Product | Date 1     | Date 2
AA      | 01/01/2018 | 01/02/2018
AB      | 01/01/2018
AC      | 01/01/2018 | 01/02/2018
```

Any suggestions would be a great help.

Thank you
Chris

Comment: What if you have three, or more, dates for a specific product?

Comment: how many dates may there be for any given Product? At most two or more?

Comment: It would be good to see them all maybe 2-5 dates but they can be ignored as the Table 2 pulls from a filtered database and only shows shipped items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Product, 
   MIN(Date) AS Date1, 
   CASE WHEN COUNT(t1.Product) > 1 THEN MAX(Date) END AS Date2
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Product = t2.Product
   GROUP BY t1.Product
```

**Try not use * in sql queries**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following query:

```sql
SELECT t1.Product, 
       MIN(Date) AS Date1, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN MAX(Date) END AS Date2
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Product = t2.Product
GROUP BY t1.Product
```

The query uses a `LEFT JOIN` to get the correlated records from `Table2` Hence, `Date1` and `Date2` are going to be `NULL` in case there is no relevant record. `Date2` is set *only if* `Product` has *at least two* correlated records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beb26c/2)